# MongoDB: Access count() from within my callback

Tags: mongodb

I use skip() and limit() to give me a page full of matching records.  I want to get the count [ which ignores skip() and limit() ] so I can know the total number of matches that would have been returned but for the skip and limit.  This will allow me to know how many pages of records exist.

Apparently, you can do that with this syntax: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count

Below is my router code.  transactions.length is just the number returned **with** the skip and limit applied, and using length, the page count will always be 1.

Instead, I need the count available to my callback.  How can I get access to the count there?

```
Transactions.getJoinedTransactions(
    global.user.firmId, page, pageSize, billerId, matterId,
    function(err, transactions) {

       if (err)
       console.log(err);

       <-- I want the count here.

       let pageCount = Math.floor(transactions.length / pageSize) + 
                       ( (transactions.length % pageSize) != 0 ? 1 : 0 );
       console.log("Matches for this page = " + transactions.length);
       console.log("Page size = " + pageSize);
       console.log("Page count = " + pageCount);

       etc.,
```

This is the database call.  Probably not necessary to the question, but just in case...

```
exports.getJoinedTransactions = function(firmId, page, pageSize, billerId, matterId, cb) {


...

Transactions.aggregate([
    { $sort: { date: -1 } },
    {
        $match: query 
    },

    ...


]).skip(numberToSkip).limit(pageSize).exec( function(err, transactions) {

    cb(err, transactions);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I need the page of transactions **and** the count of all transactions across all pages, I just got **all** the transactions without skip() and limit().

I calculated the pageCount by Math.floor(transactions.length/pageCount) (+ 1 if length % pageSize != 0).

Then, I just performed a slice() on the entire array to grab the ones I needed.  Then, I sent the err, slicedTransactions and pageCount to my callback.

Seems ok.  I have a feeling, though, that for large data sets, using all records, instead of a page-full, could cause a noticeable performance hit.